# When should I Use Method Overloading in real world Projects?

Tags: c#, .net

When Should i Use Method overloading in real time development,please suggest some links.

Comment: when you say "real time" are you implying "real life" as Henk mentioned below or are you working on a real-time software application where performance is critical? I suspect Henk is correct, but if we can help disambiquate the question the answers can be more appropriate and of course helpful to others with similar questions.

Comment: @Henk it's getting closed as it is 'difficult to  tell what is being asked' due to inclusion of the term 'real time' - it has already attracted answers about real time programming, and the question doesn't make sense in that arena. It would be better to ask the question again, without using 'real time' inappropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading is used (recommended) when multiple methods have the same purpose but there is more than one way to start it.

So we rather have

```
int Add(int a, int b) { ...}
int Add(int a, int b, int c) { ... }
```

than

```
int Add2(int a, int b) { ...}
int Add3(int a, int b, int c) { ... }
```

or

```
int Add(int a, int b, int? c) { ...}
```

The last example could also be done using (C#4) optional parameters.

Another good candidate for overloading:

```
void ReadXml(string fileName) { ... }
void ReadXml(Stream strm) { .... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Method overloading is an OOP technique used for class design. It has nothing to do with real time development.

If you are asking about real world uses of method overloading - it is a useful technique and you can see it being used all over the BCL.

Examples are some of the Linq extension methods, where many of the extension methods have multiple overloads (see [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19e6zeyy.aspx)).

Method overloads are best used when the same operation can be done in several different ways, depending on parameters - for example sorting. An overload with no parameters may apply a default sort. An overload with a sort order will allow sort order, and another one may have a `Func` delegate that determines the sort algorithm.

Comment: With a little flexibility, I read that as "real life" projects.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - fair enough... I guess I saw "real time" and immediately thought about RT programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well now with things like initializers and named parameters in c# it really doesn't seem as necessary.

Comment: One comment I would add to this is, if you were creating a public API and you wanted to really lock down how things were used then I think this would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario where method overloading could be useful is if you are building some public API. For example ASP.NET MVC use it to provide functionality through HTML helpers where you have the same method overloaded multiple times with different arguments.